# DNS resolving of Azure VMs from on-premise network

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-vpn, azure-dns

I have a problem with DNS resolving Azure machines from on-premise network connected with VPN to VMs' virtual network. In other cloud providers there are solutions to this problem, but I can't find one in Azure. In AWS I could create Inbound Route53 Endpoint which gives me IPs in the VPC that machines from my on-premise network can reach. In GCP there is forwarding DNS server policy. Is there any similar solutions in Azure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the DNS name of Azure VMs from an on-premise network, you need forward queries to your managed DNS proxy server in the corresponding virtual network, the proxy server forwards queries to Azure for resolution. The DNS servers in the virtual networks can forward DNS queries to the recursive resolvers (168.63.129.16) in Azure.

[image]

Note that Azure Private Zones does not help in this situation, you have to use your own DNS proxy server. Read [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34004).

For more references:

- [Name resolution for resources in Azure virtual networks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances)
- [Name resolution using your own DNS server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#name-resolution-that-uses-your-own-dns-server)

Comment: I thought so. Thank you.